# container after instruction doesn't work for some elements

Tags: magento2, layout, position, containers

I have created a custom theme from scratch, everything works perfectly except one thing, in my home page

```
Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

I can't place my 'main' container after my 'header' container
[image: header placed after main]
Here is the code:

```
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <container name="header.container.panel.nav" htmlTag="header" before="main.content">
            //Some stuff
        </container>
        <container name="main.content" htmlTag="main" after="header.container.panel.nav">
            //Some stuff
        </container>
    </body>
</page>
```

What I have tried:

1. Using dash instead of container name in the before and after instruction
2. Moving the definition of the main.content container before header
3. adding

```
<move element="main.content" destination="body" after="header.container.panel.nav"/>
```

Even if I'm not sure that the instruction **destination="body"** work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding a container as a parent? My idea is before/after do not work when the containers do not have a parent, and it would explain why Magento use the `root` container as a parent:

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <container name="root">
        <container name="after.body.start" as="after.body.start" before="-" label="Page Top"/>
        <container name="page.wrapper" as="page_wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-wrapper">
            <container name="global.notices" as="global_notices" before="-"/>
            <container name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlId="maincontent" htmlClass="page-main" />
            <container name="page.bottom.container" as="page_bottom_container" label="Before Page Footer Container" after="main.content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-bottom"/>
            <container name="before.body.end" as="before_body_end" after="-" label="Page Bottom"/>
        </container>
    </container>
</layout>
```

So in your example it would be:

```
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <container name="root.container">
            <container name="header.container.panel.nav" htmlTag="header" before="main.content">
                //Some stuff
            </container>
            <container name="main.content" htmlTag="main" after="header.container.panel.nav">
                //Some stuff
            </container>
        </container>
    </body>
</page>
```

If that doesn't work you could then try:

```
<move element="main.content" destination="root.container" after="header.container.panel.nav"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It helped to find the solution, you should edit your post to avoid errors i had, you should not name the container **root** because it's gonna override (I guess) another container (I named it **root.container**, so your content will be broken (I only had the view store showing). and I had to had move element for both container to make it work (for my header AND my content, else it wouldn't work)

Comment: Good stuff, I've updated my answer so it won't override the core `root` container. Thanks for the update.